# Is it possible to render a view when the server is down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to render a simple view when the server is down. There is a global filter which checks for server connection. Inside the filter a redirect should be performed to show a view when the server is.
The problem is the redirect to controller never occurs. Code inside the filter is executed several times and then I get too many requests error in the browser. 
If I Redirect to an image or text everything goes fine. But rendering a View is a no-go.

Global filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IncbbsConnection"].ToString()))
    {
        try
        { connection.Open(); }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            // This works, the text shows:
            //var content = new ContentResult {Content = "Server down!", ContentType = "text/plain"};
            // filterContext.Result = content;

            // This works, the image appears:
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Content/images/LoginLogo1.png");

            // doesn't perform redirect to a controller  
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("ServerDown",new RouteValueDictionary(new controller = "Error", action = "ServerDownView"}));
        }

        finally
        { connection.Close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well. Have you applied the filter to your Error-controller? If you've applied it globally to all controllers, the filter is going to run on every call to an action, thus checking every time, even on the Error-controller's actions...

Comment: J. Steen might be right on this one. It would possibly give a stackoverflow...

Comment: Possibly not a stack overflow, since it hands off the request to a new thread when it does that, but surely a recursive redirect. =)

Comment: so what u are saying, when it enters Error-controller it runs again & again?
is there a way to exclude a global filter from a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your filter is executed multiple times until you get a too many requests error, the problem is probably in how you have registered the filter.

A filter is applied globally by using:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new <YourFilter>);
}
```

However, this also means that your filter is applied to your `Error` controller. Your `Error` controller will detect your server is down and then redirect to itself.

You can avoid this by checking the controller in your filter:

```
if (filterContext.Controller is ErrorController)
{
    return;
}
```

This way, you won't redirect if you are already in your `ErrorController`.

Another thing I would like to point out, is that using an `ActionFilter` in this way is probably not the most optimal solution. I think that you expect that your server will be online most of the time. This code however will run on each action. Instead of using an `ActionFilter` you can implement an [ExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). That filter will only run when something actually happened. Inside your exception filter you can check the reason for your exception and if you detect the server is down redirect to your `Error` controller.

### UPDATE

After doing some research on how to exclude a global filter I found this blog post: [Conditional Filters in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx).

Phil Haack describes how you can add a custom `IFilterProvider` that won't return your filter when you are on the `Error` controller. This is a very nice implementation where you control if the filter applies outside of the actual filter.

Comment: I kind of like the conditional filters because of extreme reusability, but your original solution for extreme simplicity - and would probably use that, to avoid premature optimisation. ^^

Comment: @J.Steen I agree. If it's only about this one case with an Error Controller the first solution is way easier. The other one is probably overkill but it's just so nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the line where the problem is?

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("ServerDown",new RouteValueDictionary(new controller = "Error", action = "ServerDownView"}));
```

try changing it to:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("ServerDown",
   new RouteValueDictionary(
   new 
   {
       controller = "Error", 
       action = "ServerDownView"
   })
);
```

As far as I can see, you where missing the `{` start tag.

---

**If not that, is it a routing problem.**

There are more overloads of that RedirectToRouteResult constructor, the one you chose, you are adding in a RouteName, that means that, that route has to exist.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493020(v=vs.108).aspx

If thats the issue, just removed the route name:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
   new RouteValueDictionary(
   new 
   {
       controller = "Error", 
       action = "ServerDownView"
   })
);
```

Comment: To be fair, that line doesn't even compile, so I just think it's a mistake in copy-paste on OP's part.

Comment: My thought too, but its the only obvious issue to me. And sometimes small mistakes like that, is the showstopper.

Comment: Well. It could also be because of what I wrote in my first comment to the question. He says he's applied it **globally**, so it goes for the ErrorController, too... It matches the symptoms of "too many requests", i.e. a recursive redirect. =)

Comment: Yes, I just read your comment, that is very plausible too, it could cause endless recursion.